# Legends of two ggplot in grid.arrange() are overlapping in R Markdown

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

Legends in two ggplot graphs in grid.arrange() are overlapping. I have used legend.positon = "top" or "bottom", another problem arises i.e the ggplot is not showing complete legends. Actually, my legends are quite long. How can get legends printed in two lines to avoid above-mentioned problem?

I have tried legend.position = "top", also legend.box = "vertical" but nothing worked

```
k1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Alert,Sum, fill = Alert)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  facet_wrap(~ Model , nrow= 5) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = Sum), fontface = "bold") + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")+ 
  ggtitle("MODEL WISE ALERT COUNT")+ 
  theme_grey(base_size = 22)+
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer.

k1 %>% ggplot(aes(Alert,Sum, fill = Alert)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + facet_wrap(~ Model , nrow= 5) + coord_flip() + geom_text(aes(label = Sum), fontface = "bold") + ggtitle("MODEL WISE ALERT COUNT")+ theme_grey(base_size = 22)+theme(legend.position = "bottom") **+ guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=2,byrow=TRUE))